# How do I pass a variable using a url in php?

Tags: php, html, url, variables, parameters

When I try to pass the variable $i which is set equal to a row in my database I use this code:

window.location = 'ups?var=$i';

but it doesn't work, how would I go about passing variables via url?

Comment: That doesn't look like PHP to me. Be accurate.

Comment: @Aspyn Palatnick: try this 'ups?var=' + $i;

Answer (score 1):

you're using php variable in javascript. it won't work that way.

if you need a value of php variable in javascript:

```
window.location = 'ups?var=<?php echo $i; ?>';
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but when I tried using that code and get the $i variable from ups.php it doesn't equal anything.

Comment: if you're not setting it before it will not have a value. post the whole code if you can, I can't know what you're doing unless I see the code

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `window.location = 'ups?var=<?= $i ?>';`

Answer (score 0):

That is javascript code. In PHP:

```
header("location:ups?var=$i");
```